# Error handling in a constructor without failing

Tags: c++, validation, error-handling

I'm currently building a library that parses XML definitions for hardware configurations (obtained from the manufacturer).
I've mapped the XML types to c++ classes, and I'm making use of `std::optional` where ever there is an optional XML member when it is semantically correct for that piece of data to be missing.

I'm now trying to come up with a good error-handling strategy for my datatypes. 
Sometimes, the XML may be missing some information that is marked as `required` by the schema, or a required element might not be found (which would be a different error to an element which is missing required data).

The basic idea for all the types follows this (example) class:

```cpp
class TMyXmlType {
  std::string name;
  std::optional<int> factor;
  std::optional<int> minFactor;
  std::optional<int> maxFator;
public:
  TMyXmlType(const xml_node & root){
    if(root){ // Check if the element exists
    name = root.value();
      if(root.has_child("factor"){ factor = root.child("factor").value(); }
      if(root.has_child("minFactor"){ factor = root.child("minFactor").value(); }
      if(root.has_child("maxFator"){ factor = root.child("maxFator").value(); }
    }else{
      // What do I do here?
    }
  } 
  operator Json::Value() const {
    if(/*object constructed correctly?*/){
      Json::Value asJson;
      asJson["name"] = name;
      if(factor.has_value()){ asJson["factor"] = factor.value(); }
      if(minFactor.has_value()){ asJson["minFactor"] = minFactor.value(); }
      if(maxFator.has_value()){ asJson["maxFator"] = factor.maxFator(); }
      return asJson;
    }else{
      // return error object?
    }
  }
}
```

So far, so good. The optional members are being taken care of.
However, `root` might be an empty node (the xml parsing library returns an empty node if it wasn't found.). 
I basically want to return an error object instead of the value of the class (in my operator function) if one or more required XML nodes weren't found.

As far as I was able to find, for modern C++ you're supposed to throw an exception if the constructor can't construct the object correctly, however, if I throw an exception, my aggregate datatypes will have massive constructors with a bunch of try/catch blocks for each required data-member, which would make the codebase a pain to read and to maintain.

So now, the question is: What would be the cleanest way to have the operator return an error object instead of the class data if a required member is missing?

I don't need the constructor to explicitly fail, it currently also won't ever throw (as far as I know) and I really want error objects to give to the caller instead of return codes or bubbling exceptions.

Comment: @darune yes, I've added the `if` that checks if the node is valid, my question is about after that, what's the cleanest way to return a different object if the node was empty (in the operator function).

Comment: You don't need to handle the exception for every call - you can handle that at higher level.

Comment: Can you explain what you expect the user of your class to do if the constructor encounters an error?   In particular, how would the caller check that an error has occurred and, if so, what would it do about that?

Comment: @Peter for context, this is part of a DLL that will be called from another application. The caller of the DLL functions (which use these constructors) expects a JSON output, they can handle the JSON output on their end, but I am not allowed to raise an exception (language incompatibility). So should an error occur, ideally I want the json operator to return an object containing the error instead of the expected element.

Answer (score 0):

Plain and simple, when you don't wan't an error to fire don't do anything fancy - eg. just do:

```
class TMyXmlType {
  std::string name;
  std::optional<int> factor;
  std::optional<int> minFactor;
  std::optional<int> maxFator;
public:
  TMyXmlType(const xml_node & root){
    if(root){ // Check if the element exists
    name = root.value();
      if(root.has_child("factor"){ factor = root.child("factor").value(); }
      if(root.has_child("minFactor"){ factor = root.child("minFactor").value(); }
      if(root.has_child("maxFator"){ factor = root.child("maxFator").value(); }
    }else{
      name = "NODE_ERROR";
    }
  } 
}
```

**That being said - reconsider your design - passing an invalid node to the constructor is probably an error you don't wan't to silence and should probably fire an exception !**

(But catch the exception at a higher level - not for every construction - perhaps that is your underlying misconception)

---

Checking if a node is found for a search should be done at the level calling the search. Eg. the following code seems sensible to me:

```
const auto& node_found = searchNode(...);

const auto optXmlType = node_found ? std::make_optional<TMyXmlType>(node_found) : std::nullopt;
```

However, you might want to wrap that in a function.